# What exactly is a resource?

Tags: php

I'm working with the readfile function in php and the third parameter required is a resource. But what exactly is a resource? Could someone please give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: It's in `[]` so its NOT required.  Also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: If you go to the PHP manual - which, by the way, is excellent - you can have a look for yourself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

If you click on resource it will give you a short description of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `readfile()` and the resource is optional `[]`, if you need to use it, you'll have to provide a **context** stream resource, where **context** is a set of options that can modify the behavior of a stream.

---

[Resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

> A [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource. Resources are created and used by special functions. See the
>   [appendix](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php) for a listing of all these functions and the corresponding
>   [resource types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

Answer (score -2):

Resource is a special type for generic handler (like files, sockets, database connections). Check here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: Why didn’t you leave a comment, and vote to close the question?

Comment: Honestly I was looking for a simplified answer because the PHP manual wasn't clear enough for me in the first place, at least not dumbed down enough. Anyways it's not really that important anymore.

Comment: @MartinBean because I answered the question "what exactly is a resource?